# differential function satisfies the condition

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Let $f:[1,\infty) \rightarrow R$ is differentiable and satisfies 
$f'(x) = \ \frac{1}{x^2+f(x)^2}$ and $f(1) = 1$ 
Then

*MORE THAN ONE ANSWER MAY BE CORRECT*

1. $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$< 1+ $\frac{\pi}{4}$
2. $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$< 1+ $\frac{\pi}{3}$
3. $f'(x)$< $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$
4. $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing

I was able to prove the 3rd option and then I directly integrated it on both sides like $\int f'(x) dx< \int \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ is this the correct way to approach options 1. or 2.

Comment: in the limit an argument is missing!

Comment: @MyGlasses nope. Answer are 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since we have $$\frac{1}{x^2+f(x)^2}=f'(x)$$ we get $$\frac{1}{x^2+f(x)^2}>0$$ thus $$f'(x)>0$$
further we have $$\frac{1}{x^2+(f(x)^2}<\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ since we have $$1<f(x)^2$$

Comment: so the function is monotonically increasing huh.? what about other options ? $f'(x)$??

Comment: yes this is true

Comment: How to approach A) And B) Options.??

Comment: i don't know which limit do you mean, please correct it.

Comment: I edited the question.